# Decimal places accuracy in REDUCE operator

Tags: math, abap

In my below code, I declared `sum` and `lt_req-dmbtr` as `dmbtr`, but in the output it is not showing the decimal values and output is also less than 2 or 3 signs than the expected

```
DATA(total) = REDUCE dmbtr( INIT sum = 0  FOR wa IN lt_req WHERE ( gsber = <fs_ba_det>-gsber AND gjahr = 2020 ) NEXT sum = sum + conv dmbtr( wa-dmbtr )   ).
```

Sometimes it is thworing the error

> CX_SY_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW

Answer (score 2):

The `sum` variable type is qualificative here, not the `wa-dmbtr` you convert from.

Excerpt from [REDUCE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenconstructor_expression_reduce.htm) help:

> The declarations after INIT create local variables x1, x2
> ...

> After the full evaluation, **the content of the first variable x1** or the memory area pointed to by the first field symbol  **is assigned to the temporary result of the expression of type *type* in accordance with the assignment rules**.

And in your snippet your `sum` is zero, so it is Integer and it limits all other types.

The correct form of REDUCE to achieve your requirement:

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF ty_product,
    product TYPE char10,
    price   TYPE dmbtr,
    group   TYPE char10,
  END OF ty_product,
  tt_products TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_product WITH EMPTY KEY.

DATA(t_prod) =
  VALUE tt_products(
    ( product = 'C0001' price = '1.005'     group = 'commodities' )
    ( product = 'C0002' price = '245.48575' group = 'crude' )
    ( product = 'C0003' price = '500.05'    group = 'crude' )
    ( product = 'C0004' price = '32'        group = 'commodities' )
  ).

DATA(total) = REDUCE dmbtr( INIT sum = CONV dmbtr( 0 ) FOR wa IN t_prod WHERE ( group = 'crude' ) NEXT sum = sum + wa-price ).

WRITE total.
```

That will give **745.53575** as a result.

Comment: Note that `INIT sum TYPE dmbtr` is equivalent to `INIT sum = CONV dmbtr( 0 )`