# ABAP stop rounding when using FOR with REDUCE

Tags: abap

I am trying to sum amount using FOR and REDUCE...How do we stop rounding when using FOR with REDUCE...
example 404120.71 gets rounded to 404121.000

```
data(lv_total_sum) = reduce tslxx9( 
      init x = 0 
      for wa in lt_table
      next x = x + wa-zzamount ).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Decimal places accuracy in REDUCE operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67621770/decimal-places-accuracy-in-reduce-operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables in the `INIT` "block" are typed either explicitly or implicitly.

In your case, you assigned `0` so it's assigning implicitly the type integer (it's why you don't get the decimals):

```
data(lv_total_sum) = reduce tslxx9( init x = 0 for wa in lt_table next x = x + wa-zzamount ).
```

If you want to assign a type explicitly, you can do it this way:

```
data(lv_total_sum) = reduce tslxx9( init x TYPE tslxx9 for wa in lt_table next x = x + wa-zzamount ).
```

With `TYPE`, the variable is assigned the initial value by default.

See the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expression_reduce.htm) for more information about `REDUCE`.

EDIT: complementary solutions:

- In some cases, you may want to assign a non-initial value, like `10` below, you may then use `CONV` to assign a type :

  ```
  data(lv_total_sum) = reduce tslxx9( init x = CONV tslxx9( 10 ) for wa in lt_table next x = x + wa-zzamount ).
  ```
- When dealing with decimals, you may simply choose the biggest numeric decimal type possible, which is `decfloat34` (you may also choose a smaller one, `decfloat16`):

  ```
  data(lv_total_sum) = reduce tslxx9( init x TYPE decfloat34 for wa in lt_table next x = x + wa-zzamount ).
  ```

Comment: Thanks!!it worked